# error while starting mysql

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, database-administration

I am getting Error while starting mysql using xampp . I dont know how to fix this
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums

log file says

```
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks interlocked    functions
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 115503975998 and       115503975998 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 189324800563 in the ib_logfiles!
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
 2014-10-08 11:40:53 5788 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd  files...

 2014-10-08 11:40:53 11e8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
 InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
 InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
 InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
 InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\trillium_data\insulist_id_exist.ibd
 InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
 InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
 InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
 InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
 InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
 InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
 InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
 InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
 InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
 InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
 InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

what steps should i take?

Comment: This is your first run?

Comment: no I restarted the computer and now my mysql is not starting

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.